# How to change the parameters of the binomial distribution used in a binomial glmer?

Tags: lme4, binomial-coefficients

I wish to assess how being part of a majority helps in emerging as a leader of an animal group.

Say I have 10 cases in which I assessed whether the leader came from the majority or the minority.

```
Leader <- c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0)
Case <- as.factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
Majority <- as.factor(c("Maj","Maj","Maj","Maj","Maj","Maj","Maj","Maj","Maj","Maj",
        "Min","Min","Min","Min","Min","Min","Min","Min","Min","Min"))
leadMaj <- data.frame(Leader,Case,Majority)

binomial.glmer <- glmer(Leader ~ Majority + (1|Case),
                    family = binomial, data = leadMaj)
summary(binomial.glmer)
```

The outcome says that being from the minority drastically decreases the probability to lead the group

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Leader ~ Majority + (1 | Case)
Data: leadMaj

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  26       29      -10       20       17 

Scaled residuals: 
Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-2.0   -0.5    0.0    0.5    2.0 

Random effects:
Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
Case   (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 20, groups:  Case, 10

Fixed effects:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   1.3863     0.7906   1.754   0.0795 .
MajorityMin  -2.7726     1.1180  -2.480   0.0131 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
MajorityMin -0.707
```

However, the groups were composed of 8 individuals in the majority and 2 individuals in the minority. We can see that in 80% of the cases the majority led, which is what is expected.

So the question is: how can I include the binomial distribution with p=0.8, and not p=0.5?

Comment: the function glmer comes from package lm4 correct?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: glmer is from the 'lme4' package, lme4::glmer